# Remove upper and right coordinate bars OxyPlot

Tags: c#, wpf, coordinates, coordinate-systems, oxyplot

I am using C # WPF application with OxyPlot

[The coordinate system looks like this so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1tbo.png)

[I would like to remove the upper and the right coordinate labels.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNtlT.png)

The code looks as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="TestOxyPlot.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestOxyPlot"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <oxy:Plot x:Name="oxyPlot" Title="{Binding Title}" Margin="207,53,0,0">
            <oxy:Plot.Axes>
                <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Bottom" MinimumPadding="0.1" MaximumPadding="0.1"/>
                <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Right" MinimumPadding="0.1" MaximumPadding="0.1"/>
                <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Left" MinimumPadding="0.1" MaximumPadding="0.1" AxislineStyle="None"/>
                <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Top" MinimumPadding="0.1" MaximumPadding="0.1" AxislineStyle="None"/>
            </oxy:Plot.Axes>

            <oxy:Plot.Series>
                <oxy:LineSeries x:Name="ls" ItemsSource="{Binding Points}" LineStyle="None"  MarkerType="Square" MarkerSize="5" MarkerFill="Black"/>
            </oxy:Plot.Series>

        </oxy:Plot>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="44,64,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" MouseLeave="textBox_MouseLeave" TextChanged="textBox_TextChanged"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="44,101,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" TextChanged="textBox1_TextChanged"/>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,174,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I thought

> AxislineStyle="None"

Would help

So I hope hr can tell me how I can remove the upper and right labeling of the axes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried removing `<oxy:LinearAxis Position="Left"` and `<oxy:LinearAxis Position="Top"` ??

Comment: No thanks. But that was the solution.
I wanted to use a border and thought this would be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `TextColor = "Transparent"` in your `LinearAxis`. Furthermore, there are other properties to adjust the appearance:

```
  MinorTickSize="0" TickStyle="Crossing"
```

Comment: @GabelUndMesser Please let me know if it did not solve your problem.